# How to access nested objects in strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I'm quite new to rails API. I'm having trouble on how can I access the :guest object from the params. What I want to to do is to create a new record in Booking and Guest. Thank you.

Booking Controller

```
attr_accessor :guest 

def create
    booking = Booking.new(reservation_params)
    booking.guest.build({booking_id: booking.id, first_name: ?, last_name: ?})
end

def reservation_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:start_date, :end_date :guest => [:first_name, :last_name])
end
```

POST

```
{
    "start_date": "2021-03-12",
    "end_date": "2021-03-16",
    "guest": {
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. You're assigning a local variable - not an instance variable.

```
attr_accessor :guest 

def create
    booking = Booking.new(reservation_params)
end
```

Here you might assume that since you declared a setter with `attr_accessor` that this would set the instance variable `@booking` so that you can access it from the view? Wrong. When performing assignment you need to explicitly set the recipient unless you want to assign a local variable.

```
attr_accessor :guest 

def create
   self.booking = Booking.new(reservation_params)
end
```

But you could actually just write `@booking = Booking.new(reservation_params)` since that setter is not actually doing anything of note.

#### 2. Models don't have an id until they are saved.

This line:

```
booking.guest.build({booking_id: booking.id, first_name: ?, last_name: ?})
```

Is actually equivilent to:

```
booking.guest.build(booking_id: nil, first_name: ?, last_name: ?)
```

One big point of assocations is that the ORM takes care of linking the records for you. Let it do its job. If you're ever assigning an id manually in Rails you're most likely doing it wrong.

#### 3. You're not saving anything to the DB

`.new` (build is just an alias for new) just instanciates an new model instance. You need to actually save the object for it to have any effect beyond the current request.

### How do I fix it?

If you want to use that parameter structure it can be done with a bit of slicing and dicing:

```
def create
  @booking = Booking.new(reservation_params.except(:guest)) do |b|
    b.guest.new(reservation_params[:guest])
  end
  if @booking.save
    redirect_to @booking
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

The reason you use `except(:guest)` to remove the `guest` param  is that the setter defined by the assocation expects an instance of guest and not a hash so it will blow up otherwise

#### Nested attributes

`accepts_nested_attributes` is the *Rails way* of passing attibutes through another model. It expects the parameter to be named `guest_attributes` not `guest`.

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :guest
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guest
end
```

If you really need to use the existing params structure you can just alter the parameters in your whitelisting method:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    @booking = Booking.new(reservation_params)
    if @booking.save
      redirect_to @booking
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:booking)
          .permit(:start_date, :end_date, guest: [:first_name, :last_name])
          .tap do |p|
            # replaces the key :guests with :guest_attributes 
            p.merge!(guest_attributes: p.delete(:guest))
          end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally understand it. Although I encountered an error "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for nil:NilClass>".
I tried to render json the reservation_params and it renders null in the guest_attributes. Also null in  reservation_params[:guest_attributes]. Any idea how to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: That's really a separate question with a different starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create two associated models as once, you can use:
`accepts_nested_attributes_for`.
In the booking model add:

```
# models/booking.rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :guest
```

And then in the controller:

```
def reservation_params
  params.require(:boking).permit(:start_date,...,
                                 guest_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name])
end
```

And then you can just create the booking including the guest like so:

```
booking = Booking.new(reservation_params)
```

Find more info here:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: This answer does assume that you can change the incoming parameters though which may not be possible.

Comment: Thank you I was able to make it work, I just tweak something but somehow it does not create a record to its associated model?

Comment: You're assigning `booking_id: booking.id` but since the record is not saved you're assigning nil. You're also not saving anything.